# R boxplot ordering X axis by date

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data set which is like this:

`temp   date
14.09   Aug-13
16.9    Aug-13
16.93   Aug-13
17.7    Sep-13
17.79   Sep-13
17.94   Sep-13
17.04   Oct-13
16.98   Oct-13
16.95   Oct-13
11.9    Nov-13
11.97   Nov-13
12.04   Nov-13`

and so on for at least three years of values (from Jan-12 to Dec-14)....
I would like to create a box plot where the x axis (date) are ordered not alphabetically but by month, in the correct order (jan feb mar apr may....).
I know I could create a vector and manually order my date, but since the data set is big (at least 3 years of values) I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(zoo)
df2 <- df1[order(as.yearmon(df1$date, '%b-%y')),]
boxplot(temp~ factor(date, levels=unique(date)), df2)
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(temp = c(11.9, 37.7, 17.7, 18.04, 16.93, 25.95, 
12.04, 17.94, 16.9, 17.79, 24.93, 26.9, 15.94, 17.04, 11.97, 
13.97, 15.09, 17.79, 19.98, 12.9, 14.09, 16.95, 16.98, 14.04), 
date = c("Nov-13", "Sep-15", "Sep-13", "Oct-14", "Aug-13", 
"Oct-14", "Nov-13", "Sep-13", "Aug-13", "Sep-13", "Aug-15", 
"Aug-14", "Sep-15", "Oct-13", "Nov-13", "Nov-14", "Aug-14", 
"Sep-15", "Oct-15", "Nov-14", "Aug-13", "Oct-13", "Oct-13", 
"Nov-14")), .Names = c("temp", "date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: @luca Not able to reproduce the error using this example dataset.  I am using `R 3.1.2`

Comment: the same...R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet".  I am able to order the data set (with your code). but then trying the box plot i got the error...

Comment: @luca Are you getting the error using the `dput` dataset posted by me.

Comment: Solved! Thank you! I got the error because I was using another library to produce the box plot (with the command bplot). But copying exactly your code worked out my problem! Thanks!